# How to efficiently sort an array of doubles without libraries?

Tags: c++, c, sorting

I'm looking for an efficient way to sort an array of doubles. I know bubble sort and selection sort, neither of them seems to be fast enough. I read about quick sort, but I don't understand how it works. There are a lots of example source codes, but all of them are poorly commented. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Have you learned binary trees yet?

Comment: "*Can someone please show the implementation*" That's not a good usage of Stack Overflow **or** homework.

Comment: Bubble sort and selection sort are both `O(n^2)` algorithms - about as slow as sorting can (sensibly) be. There are a host of much faster `O(n log(n))` algorithms; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) is a good starting point for your research. [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is a popular choice.

Comment: quicksort is one of the easy sorts to implement. This is a question [google](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort) should answer for you.

Comment: CookieOfFortune- I did learn binary trees, and I know you can search faster in them, but I didn't use them for sorting.
Drew Dormann- Using this site for homework was not my intuition, I can basically get away with qsort, since a computer does the testing.

Comment: Your source code is limited to 1500 *bytes*?  Or lines?

Comment: try to code quicksort or mergesort or even heapsort by yourself. They are more efficient than selection sort and bubble sort. quicksort sorts array in place and does not need additional memory.

Comment: @user2230168 It's difficult to understand what you're asking.  Is it "show me the implementation" or "help me understand quicksort"?  Or something else?

Comment: Alright, I will feed you: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/lib/sort.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this after getting an idea about how qsort works. I do think qsort is not that easy to understand. It would probably need some optimalization, and is probably no where compared to the original qsort, but here it is. Thanks for peaple who tried to help with this.

```
/*recursive sorting, throws smaller values to left,
bigger to right side, than recursively sorts the two sides.*/
void sort(double szam[], int eleje, int vege){
  if (vege > eleje + 1){            //if I have at least two numbers
    double kuszob = szam[eleje];    //compare values to this.
    int l = eleje + 1;              //biggest index that is on the left.
    int r = vege;                   //smallest index that is on the right side.
    while (l < r){                  //if I haven't processed everything.
      if (szam[l] <= kuszob) l++;   //good, this remains on the left.
      else
        swap(&szam[l], &szam[--r]); //swap it with the farthest value we haven't checked.
    }
    swap(&szam[--l], &szam[eleje]); //make sure we don't compare to this again, that could cause STACK OVERFLOW
    sort(szam, eleje, l);           //sort left side
    sort(szam, r, vege);            //sort right side
  }
  return;                           //if I have 1 number break recursion.
}
```